# Azure DevOps REST Api - Authentication aside from PAT using .NET

Tags: .net, authentication, azure-devops, active-directory

first: I am not that familiar with authentication stuff.

I have a WPF net6 Desktop application accessing a Azure DevOps instance using the REST API for reading workitems, repos, pull requests and other stuff. This application currently uses a PAT to access the API.
Every user of the application has the same rights. Our Azure instance is connected to the Active directory.

That is kind of a problem, as either the user has to enter its own PAT on startup, or I have to store a single PAT in the repo, which is a security issue.

I am looking for other authentication methods, Microsofts lists them here: https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/authentication/authentication-guidance?view=azure-devops

1. Unfortunatly, interactive client seems to be not supported when using higher framework than net48.
2. OAuth(2) is, as I understood it, registering the application type server-side to get a secret. But than I have the problem of where to store the secret?
3. Is there a possibility to simply use the Active directory to use the currently logged in user credentials to authenticate? How is this called (Microsoft Entra?)?
4. Another option?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Hi there, May I know if you have got a chance to test with the code samples in this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/authentication/authentication-guidance?view=azure-devopst) and if any of them can meet your requirements?

Comment: check this doc https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/authentication/oauth?view=azure-devops